# How to search a CSV file using the .find method in python?

Tags: python, csv

I know there is alot of people that are familiar with the .find method , I've recently came across a project were I've needed to search through a csv file for matching data and ive came up with a simple solution using the .find method.
Ive seen multiple questions around the subject , but nun considered this method.

## contents of .csv file :

```
First,last,email,salary,DOB,occupation
kisha,smith,kishasmith@gmail.com,40000,1-1-2029,janitor
bob,smith,smithbob@gmail.com,400000,1-3-2003,developer
```

Comment: did you just posted a question just to answer it by yourself?

Comment: Its the Q/A format.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution , a `for` loop 
i went ahead and threw it in a method so its re-useable

```
def check(a):
    with open('#your csv file' , 'r')as csv_read_file:
     for lines in csv_read_file:
            if lines.find(a) > -1:
                print(lines)
```

we simply opened the csv file in `read` mode

```
with open('#your csv file' , 'r')as csv_read_file:
```

created our for loop to loop through the information in the `.csv` file

```
for lines in csv_read_file:
```

using the .find method  , if the string you search for is not located in the line , then you will get back the value -1 , therefor we searched to see if `a` , was in the line by using the `>` comparison to confirm its existence

```
if lines.find(a) > -1:
                print(lines)
```